# API call is not executing until a seemingly unrelated async function finishes. How can I make them run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, async-await

This is written in Vue but I suspect it's more a general JS question.

In the component:

```
<button @click="apiCall()">Click Me</button>
```

In Vue methods:

```
async apiCall() {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("stuff", this.stuff);

    this.data = await fetch('/api-1', {
            body: form,
            method: "POST",
        })
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((j) => {
                return j.data;
            });
}
```

While that is doing it's thing and I'm waiting for this.data, I have another API call I would like to make, based on what's going into an input. I've simplified the code for this question but I don't see any way these depend on each other or interact with one another. They seem to me to be completely independent.

In the component:

```
<input v-model="text" @input="secondApiCall()" />
```

In Vue methods:

```
secondApiCall() {
 axios
      .post("/api-2", {
        text: this.text,
      })
      .then((r) => {
        console.log("r.data");
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
 }
```

The first call is one large request that takes awhile. The second is a bunch of small requests - it's an autocomplete. What I see when I console.log the results of the autocomplete is a long pause while the first call is processing - and then it spits out everything I'd done during that time. So the inputs are being recorded and then either all sent at once or the data is only given to me at the end. I would expect it to ignore everything I'm typing given it's not working as expected, but it's not ignoring the typing. It just isn't streaming the results - until the first call has finished.

---

Update: from comments and testing, it appears this is **not** a JavaScript issue but Laravel and possibly the fact that I'm doing localhost development. My knowledge of this aspect is very limited but it seems to be related to doing simultaneous calls to Laravel and it's waiting until the last one finishes. For now, I'm setting up queued jobs and broadcasting but if someone can answer how to make Laravel process multiple separate requests from the client, without waiting for the last one to finish, that would be awesome. And again, specifically using localhost.

Comment: Can you make sure your API server is responsive when executing the big request? Could be lack of server resources. Or, in case of a dev server, not serving concurrent threads used to be a common issue.

Comment: @RubyRacer thank you, i will expand the question to include that information.

Comment: Create an endpoint on the server that does nothing but to delay the response. No CPU power. For example, a sleep command. If the autocomplete works, then I would check server load. Other than that, you can check developer console, network tab, to see if the requests fire and stall or if they wait for the first request to finish

Comment: Autocomplete does not work when api hits /sleep and all it does is sleep(100)

Comment: `either all sent at once or the data is only given to me at the end` you should be able to see which of these is the case by monitoring the requests in the developer tools network tab

Comment: In Network tab all of the autocompletes show up while it's sleeping, and they say Status (pending)

Comment: Then it's definitely not a JS issue.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be Laravel. Thank you all. If anyone has a Laravel solution please add it. At present, I'm setting up queued jobs and broadcasting as a workaround. But I suspect there is a quicker fix if I just knew how to do it.